# How do I make this image show properly?

Tags: html, css, web

[image] So, I want to make this image show fully. Heres my code so far:

Link: https://summit.tahaparacha1.repl.co/

HTML:

```
        <div class="header">
        <h1>Learn Mathmatics In Minutes!</h1>
        <h3>Increase your knowledge with Summit! Summit allows you discover the endless possiblities you probably thought never exsisted. Start learning for free at your own pace now, or scroll down to see what we offer.</h3>

        <a class="grow "href="#">Start Learning</a>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
.header {
    background-image: url("images/SummitHome1.jpg");
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
}
```

Comment: Please edit your post and make [a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: It seems to show fully, but the user has to scroll up as there is space above the header element. Could you describe a bit more what you require it to look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking for the [`background-size` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size).

Though i'm not sure i understand your wish well enough, to determine which of the options you'd want. `cover` or `contain` ?

Comment: Ah yes, however it shows more of the image with the "background-size" but the bottom of the image is still cut off. Heres what it looks like now: https://summit.tahaparacha1.repl.co/

Comment: I think that is because you gave it a height of 100vh (which is fine) but you also have a large top margin on the `.header` , so it all shifts down. If you do `.header { margin: 0; }` and (temporarily) set `.nav { opacity: 0.5 }` then you can probably see whats going on.

Comment: Thanks, the white box at the top is gone, but I still don't know whats wrong with the image? Do you think you could take a look at my repl?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "whats wrong with the image", there doesn't really seem anything wrong with it. It's likely displayed in a different way than you have in mind, but its not clear to me what way that is exactly.

Comment: Hey, thanks! I fixed it while you were away, but thanks anyways!